# How to implement tab completion in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tabs

I am trying to use the getopt module in Python where I have defined a parameter **-p** to be added by user while running my script. Here is the script

```
def usage():
    print "Usage: "
    print "my.py -p <path to file>"

try:
    options, remainder=getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'p:h')

except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print str(err)
    usage()
    sys.exit()


for opt, arg in options:
    if opt in ('-p'):
        file_path=arg
    if opt in ('-h'):
        usage()
    sys.exit()
```

The script is run like my.py -p . for e.g.

```
my.py -p /home/charts_test
```

Now, the problem is that when I try run the script, I need to cpy and paste the path as standard tab completion does not work. How can I implement the same for my script?

I googled for os module functions in python, but could not find any.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean the tab completion in the **shell** that you're using.

Comment: Yes, like when I start typing the path in parameter -p, say /home and then press tab, it should become /home/charts_test (like in shell or linux). I am running the script in linux.

Comment: That is not a concern of python as the python process is not even running; you're just forming the command in the shell. No module will help you. Look into your shell's completion tools and how to configure them. As an aside, have a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) module. It is rather nicer than `getopt` and provides usage print outs for free, among other things.

Comment: You are correct, I just checked and its working. Strange that it was not working yesterday. This sounds weird but I don't know what happened exactly. Thank you for your prompt response.